# How can I configure the Lubuntu Update Notifier to pop up less often?

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

Ever since I installed Lubuntu 20, the Update Notifier keeps popping up around every other day.

[image]

If I don't update, it keeps annyoing me multiple times per day. This is way too often, especially since I don't know if an update will require a subsequent restart. So:

1. How can I schedule the Update Notifier, for example to something like "check every month (only), and if I don't update right away, ask back no earlier than 6 hours later"?
2. When the Update Notifier informs me about new updates, how can I know if starting the installation would require a subsequent restart?

I was not able to find this information on Google or in the Lubuntu manual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the time after which you will receive a update notification, then you need to open the /usr/lib/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu_upg_notifer.sh file and change the `sleep 3600` line. This line indicates that the script will sleep 3600 after the first update notification after startup. If you do not want any update notifications to come at all, then you need <s>to completely remove (or comment) the content of the script</s> just delete `/etc/xdg/autostart/upg-notifier-autostart.desktop` autostart file.

[Commented update notifer script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYBb2.png)